# Can I change a gradient's color stops by dragging colors from other objects?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, gradient

[image]

I'd like to change the white-to-black gradient to one with the colors in the rectangles on the top left. How can I drag these colors onto the gradient?

Comment: you could use the `swatches` palette to store the two rectangles' colours and then use the swatches when editing the gradient fill.

Comment: ok thank you bro. but how can i add this colors ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on one stop of the gradient or create a new one, press <kbd>I</kbd> to invoke eyedropper, hold shift and select a color of any object -  it will be added to the stop.

Answer (score 0):

This is an older tutorial but a good introduction to using gradients and swatches in Illustrator, it really helped me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jPQxbIvSNJI

Comment: Hi there! I just thought I would offer some unsolicited advice : ) Answers that consist on links to another site tend to be down-voted or ignored. The reason behind this is that this community tries to create its own database of answers, so it can be used in the future by other users with the same question. If you just provide a link and the other site decides to remove or change the page, then your answer becomes useless and broken. You can always provide a link, of course, but it is a good idea to summarize (using your own words) in your answer the info that can be found in the linked page.

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the colors in the colors swatches window. Select one of your rectagle and then, in the swatches window, click the "New Swatch" and add your color. Then you can drag your color to your gradient window